# Переход на новый домен без вреда для индексации сайта в поисковиках

Tags: домен

Дайте, пожалуйста, ссылку на какую нибудь хорошую статью, где подробно написано, как надо переходить на новый домен без вреда для индексации сайта в поисковиках.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А это вообще возможно? Дело в том, что поисковики индексируют ваш контент, привязывая его к имени сайта. Если меняется домен, то меняется и имя сайта, что приводит к индексации заново! Это происходит даже при изменении имени сайта, а не то, что домена. Я с этим сталкивался (во втором случае), так что - НЕТ!!! Всё заново!

Я, честно, очень не хотел отвечать на этот вопрос потому, что не люблю слова "НЕТ". Надеялся, что Гуры наши это прояснят. Но Гуры молчали, и пришлось мне отдуваться!

Answer (score 1):

Статью подсказать не могу, но если новый домен основным, а при запросе со старого сделать редирект на новый, то все должно получится.

Comment: Я так понял, что если бы работал старый, то не было бы нужды и в новом!